# Identifying work items which have been released via VSTS API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Trying to determine which VSTS Work Items have been released to a given Environment (production). Ideally looking for a Service Hook to tell me when work items are deployed so we can keep the rest of the company updated on when items are deployed.

Cannot find this available in the VSTS API.

In the VSTS UI under the Release Summary tab it shows linked Work Items. However linked Work Items don't appear to be available via the API.
[VSTS API docs for Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/get%20release?view=vsts-rest-5.0)

In the VSTS UI under each Work Item, it shows when it was integrated into a build, however not when that build has been released.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question:

> Ideally looking for a Service Hook to tell me when work items are
>   deployed so we can keep the rest of the company updated on when items
>   are deployed.

The deployed work items information is already included in the Release Deployment Service Hooks as below:
[image]
So you just need to create a Service Hook for Release deployment completed event and create a web service to listen on this.

Answer (score 4):

There's a REST API, you're just looking in the wrong place for it. BTW, you can find this stuff easily by looking at the network traffic in the F12 tools in your browser.

`https://<accountUrl>/<Project>/_apis/Release/releases/<ReleaseID>/workitems?baseReleaseId=<ReleaseToCompareAgainst>&%24top=250`

Comment: Where is the documentation for that? As far as I'm aware that endpoint is specific to the on-premises TFS only and not available as an endpoint for the hosted VSTS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/get%20release?view=vsts-rest-4.1

Comment: Thanks - this works, even though it isn't documented.