# Is there a way to find the workitems for a release in Azure DevOps Api 5.1?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I can find a release in Azure DevOps Api 5.1 by a request to https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_apis/release/releases/myreleaseid?api-version=5.1

How can I get the workitems of that release as shown on the devops portal under Deployment - Stages - Workitems?

My naive approach just using  https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_apis/release/releases/myreleaseid/workitems?api-version=5.1

resulted in a 404.

There is a stakeholder in the workitem and I want to send him a notification adter the release.

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Can the rest api below work on your side?

Comment: Yes realy works. Good idea to use F12 tools for undocumented queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the workitems of that release as shown on the devops
>   portal under Deployment - Stages - Workitems?

Hard to say, but I don't find any document about this topic... So I determine to use F12 to find that. And here's the one I finally find:

**Get**:`https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_apis/Release/releases/myreleaseId/workitems?baseReleaseId={my baseReleaseId}&%24top=250&artifactAlias={my artifactAlias}`

It will returns the IDs of the workItems for the release. Its response format:

[image]

After you get the IDs, it's easy to get details if you need using [Get Work Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) or what.

**In addition:**

1.myreleaseId is the ReleaseID. (On my side, the ID is 7 if it's Release-7)

2.`my artifactAlias` is this:

[image]

3.For `my baseReleaseId`, I'm not 100% sure about its meaning. I think it could be something like `ReleaseToCompareAgainst`. Hint from [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51843519/10910450). (On my side, if my releaseId=7, then I use basereleaseID=6(7-1), it works to get the correct WIT ids). (Actually I suggest you can use F12 in that web page to check your corresponding URL.)

And according to **Mathias F**: The baseReleaseId realy is the last previous release that has a deployment (-1 in some cases)

4.About how to use F12 to find rest api which may not be documented:

[image]

Hope all above helps :)

Comment: The baseReleaseId realy is the last previous release that has a deployment (-1 in some cases)