# which api will get me the Work Items related to the release pipeline?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, I have a CI pipeline which generates an artifact. As soon as the Pull Request gets approved, it triggers a release pipeline. In the release pipeline, I have added a PowerShell task to perform some REST API functions. I am trying to get all the work items associated with this release. and for that i used below api but i get page not found. Can anyone direct me to the correct api which needs to be called in order to get the workitems associated with my release pipeline.

*/_apis/Release/releases/$releaseid/workitems?api-version=6.0*

here is the powershell snippet which i am trying to call, here release id is called by defining the predefined variable in powershell task in release pipeline

```
Function GET-WORKRELEASE{

$AzureDevOpsPAT = "wiosoqn4x66brkkcntesttesttesta"
$OrganizationName = "thru"
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }
$orz = "https://dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/thru"
$d=''
$uriAccount = $orz + "/_apis/Release/releases/$releaseid/workitems?api-version=6.0" 
$responsewe = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader 
$d1 = $responsewe.value | ConvertTo-Json

write-host $d1
}
```

Comment: what is the question? the script didn't work? did you get an error?

Comment: hi, i am looking for the right api to get all the work items associated with my release pipeline. i have edited the question now

Comment: Check this article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/how-to-retrieve-all-work-items-associated-with-a-release-pipeline-using-azure-devops-api/

Comment: yes i have seen this, but my requirement requires me to call api from a powershell scripts... i was hoping if i can get direction in powershell as it seems there are multiple apis to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api to `get Work Items related to the release pipeline` is not documented, it should be:

```
Get: https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/Release/releases/{ReleaseId}/workitems?baseReleaseId={BaseReleaseId}&%24top=250&artifactAlias={ArtifactAlias}
```

`{OrgName}`: Your organization name.

`{ProjectName}`: Your corresponding project name.

`{ReleaseId}`:

[image]

`{BaseReleaseId}`: The last previous release that has a deployment,
`BaseReleaseId = ReleaseId-1` in some cases. If ReleaseId is `12`, the BaseReleaseId is `11` in most cases.

`{ArtifactAlias}`:

[image]

For more details you can check my [another thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61133262/10910450).

And your PS script should be changed to:

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$OrganizationName = "xxxxxx"
$ProjectName = "xxxxxx"
$ReleaseId = "xx"
$BaseReleaseId = "xx" 
$ArtifactAlias = "_xxx"
#*********************************************************************************
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }
$orz = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/$($ProjectName)"
$uriAccount = $orz + "/_apis/Release/releases/$($ReleaseId)/workitems?baseReleaseId=$($BaseReleaseId)&%24top=250&artifactAlias=$($ArtifactAlias)"
$responsewe = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlAccount -Method Get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
$d1 = $responsewe.value | ConvertTo-Json
write-host $d1
```

You only need to configure the variables above `#**************************`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use following API:
[https://{organizationName}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseid}/workitems?api-version=6.0-preview](https://%7BOrganizationName%7D.vsrm.visualstudio.com/%7BProject%7D/_apis/Release/releases/%7BReleaseid%7D/workitems?api-version=6.0-preview)

You would need to modify snippet as below:

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = "************************"
$OrganizationName = "YourOrgName"
$Project = "YourProject"
$releaseid=releaseID
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }
$orz = "https://$($OrganizationName).vsrm.visualstudio.com/$($Project)"
$uriAccount = $orz + "/_apis/Release/releases/$($releaseid)/workitems?api-version=6.0-preview" 
$responsewe = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader 
$d1 = $responsewe.value | ConvertTo-Json
write-host $d1
```